# Cannot use same cookie for multiple GWT applications

Tags: session, gwt, cookies

I am developing an application network where I want to offer multiple applications to my users with them only having to register/login a single time and use all of the applications with the same login.

To achieve this, I created a cookie in which I store the Session ID of the user(which he receives when he logs in). Everytime a user opens up an application, the Launch Module tries to find the cookie and sends a request to the server to check if that session is still valid.

When I tested this on my local dev machine, everything worked fine, but on my pre-live test server, the cookie I created in the one application is not found by the other application.

My Test Server is a Tomcat 7.
Apllications deployed via .war-upload

Cookies are initially created using this command: `Cookies.setCookie("WebsiteName", result.getSessionId());`

Every Help is appreciated!

**Edit 1**

I got a little bit further on getting everything to work as I wanted it.

Originally I did not implement the HttpServlet Session, but an own Session management System, which stored my own session ID in the cookie. Checking the Server Logs, I found out, that if both applications are deployed under a sub path, the Session Output is the following for application 1:

```
Test HttpSession ID: 34446C7F3F345F74A0AAB5E292A47021 | Own Session ID: 3a25884692c499d5e72f07bb2b214a40f63f5a4a842852c58f30e1b46cf7bee7bc8a3394a9fe83a04ac4e1dcb4069dbca95a8f0001e012bc643934e08af35ec2
```

AND for application 2

```
Test HttpSession ID: 429388DE8F0F76F877B077433FE16B66 | Own Session ID: 4e6b19a7621893de0cd0826b298ea4d8eb5ffecf4a7503f3274f729c2df28f4a1e9ce52179730b4139804f256591149fd712be76ad3afd87bade4f58aab4234f
```

I had the suspicion that Tomcat generates another Session ID for every web application, so I renamed my main application's .war-File to `ROOT.war` and deployed it as the Root application. The Output was the following for the ROOT apllication:

```
Test HttpSession ID: B9F2D14A716C3A06E328F58ED0995D95 | Own Session ID: 039b1c0cd2726dcfa1d8585da589e05984cfb6c971e083423d8456673837ea954ead42728aecf93be358ed13c757e3848ee3eb061a2253350c7d6dc1a14c970c
```

AND for the apllication at path `root/webapp1/`:

```
Test HttpSession ID: BFD836C297B1BF8204D243387401CCA7 | Own Session ID: 039b1c0cd2726dcfa1d8585da589e05984cfb6c971e083423d8456673837ea954ead42728aecf93be358ed13c757e3848ee3eb061a2253350c7d6dc1a14c970c
```

The own Session ID is stored in the cookie and checked by the server. My conclusion is, that the browsers create Different cookies for each subpath of my domain.

Adding a Domain name to the Cookie finally did the trick, silly me :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked the logs? What is the error are you getting in the logs or developer tool console (firebug?)?. A detailed log would be helpful in getting answer.

However the approach you are trying is definitely possible, if you have followed the correct approach.

**Step 1** : Create a session

```
 void createSession(String Username) 
 {
    getThreadLocalRequest().getSession().setAttribute("Username", Username);
 }
```

**Step 2** : Set the cookie properly

```
String sessionID = /*(Get sessionID from server's response to your login request.)*/;
final long DURATION = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 14; 
Date expires = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + DURATION);
Cookies.setCookie("sessionId", sessionID, expires, null, "/", false);
```

**Step 3** : Validate the user session from the cookie you have set and user credentials.

```
boolean sessionAndUserValidFlag = false;
String sessionID = Cookies.getCookie("sessionId");
if ( sessionID != null )
{
   sessionAndUserValidFlag = validateSession(sessionID);
}
if (sessionAndUserValidFlag)
{
   //Continue login
}
else
{
  //Display Login Popup
}
```

**Your validateSession method may look something like this**

```
public boolean validateSession(String sessionId)
{
    if (getThreadLocalRequest().getSession().getId.equals(sessionId))
    {
       if ( getThreadLocalRequest().getSession().getAttribute("UserName") != null )
       {
             return true;
       }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I added some edits to my question about what I found out to solve the problem. Finally it was just a missing domain declaration when setting my cookie. Thanks four your help!