# GWT: Login Remember me

Tags: session, gwt, authentication

I try to understand this [Login example](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/LoginSecurityFAQ). 
There is a procedure called "checkWithServerIfSessionIdIsStillLegal".
I am wondering how the server can validate if a session is still valid because the session id is always different when the user closes the browser. 
Can someone explain me how does this work?

Answer (score 0):

By setting session id in onModule load(when he `logs in`) as a cookie and checking again after he accessing login page.

```
         String sessionID = result.getSessionId();
         final long DURATION = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 1;
         Date expires = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + DURATION);
         Cookies.setCookie("sid", sessionID, expires, null, "/", false);
```

Here is the complete implemetation of [checkWithServerIfSessionIdIsStillLegal()](http://varuntayur.wordpress.com/2012/01/25/session-management-in-gwt/),which you are referring.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following link.

[Cannot use same cookie for multiple GWT applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14305654/cannot-use-same-cookie-for-multiple-gwt-applications/14306386#14306386)

This might solve your problem.